# Java Reactive get ServerRequest body, run repository and return flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I was trying to get the body of "users" in HttpRequest body from ServerRequest. I am using RouterFunction for this. This "users" key contains a list of users.

After that, I need to extract this list of users to get the Flux from a repository and return back to frontend. How can I achieve that?

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    Flux<Account> findByUserIn(List userList);
}
```

**How to modify the below code for it to work?**

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getUserList(ServerRequest request) {

        Flux<User> users = request.bodyToMono(String.class).doOnSuccess(x -> {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(x);
            List userList= jObject.getJSONArray("users").toList();
            userRepository.findByUserIn(userList);
        })
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(users, Repo.class);
    }
```

Comment: Use flatMap and not doOnSuccess

Comment: it is flatMapMany, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, stuck because of a few typos, and thanks to Toerktumlare pointing it out. I need to use flatMapMany.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getUserList(ServerRequest request) {

    Flux<User> results = request.bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMapMany(x -> {
                JSONObject req = new JSONObject(x);
                List userList = req.getJSONArray("users").toList();
                return userRepository.findByUserIn(userList);
            });
    return ServerResponse.ok().body(results, User.class);
}
```